# Open user in skype-for-business(Lync)

Tags: c#, lync, skype-for-business

I am writing application that should open user in skype-for-business(Lync) app

I tried to use Lync SDK 2013 API ,but this a ability dose not exist.

```
    public LyncControler()
    {
        LyncClient lyncClient= LyncClient.GetClient();
        IAsyncResult state2 = lyncClient.ContactManager.BeginSearch("User a", callback1, state);
    }

    private void callback1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var type = ar.GetType();
        var str = ar.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What version of Skype for Business are you using?

Comment: @EdneyHolder Microsoft Lync 2013 (15.0.5153.1001) MSO (15.0.5153.100) 32-bit